# Custom Pagination: $this in "pagination_item_active" function is not in object context?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, pagination

Joomla 3

I was trying to modify Joomla's pagination output. Following this [documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides#Pagination_Links_Overrides), I create `mytemplate/html/pagination.php` file and start modifying it. According to the document, I can write 4 functions in the new pagination file, I actually just want to rewrite `_list_render()` and `_item_active()`. However, in `libraries/cms/pagination/pagination.php` beginning from line 327

```
    $chromePath = JPATH_THEMES . '/' . $this->app->getTemplate() . '/html/pagination.php';

    if (file_exists($chromePath))
    {
        include_once $chromePath;

        if (function_exists('pagination_item_active') && function_exists('pagination_item_inactive'))
        {
            $itemOverride = true;
        }

        if (function_exists('pagination_list_render'))
        {
            $listOverride = true;
        }
    }
```

This means I can only get CMS to use my function if only both `pagination_item_active()` and `pagination_item_inactive()` exist. But I don't have my own `pagination_item_active()`, so I copy the content of `_item_active()` in the CMS's pagination.php to my override file so it looks like this in my pagination.php

```
......
function pagination_item_active(JPaginationObject $item){
  $title = '';
  $class = '';

  if (!is_numeric($item->text))
  {
    JHtml::_('bootstrap.tooltip');
    $title = ' title="' . $item->text . '"';
    $class = 'hasTooltip ';
  }

  if ($this->app->isAdmin())
  {
    return '<a' . $title . ' href="#" onclick="document.adminForm.' . $this->prefix
    . 'limitstart.value=' . ($item->base > 0 ? $item->base : '0') . '; Joomla.submitform();return false;">' . $item->text . '</a>';
  }
  else
  {
    return '<a' . $title . ' href="' . $item->link . '" class="' . $class . 'pagenav">' . $item->text . '</a>';
  }
```

}

The problem is, when I run the PHP, I get this error message:

> Using $this when not in object context in
>
> /home/w/public_html/templates/rt_photon/html/pagination.php on line 56

What I don't understand is, my pagination.php is supposed to be included into the CMS's one, where there is an "object context", why then is it giving this error message? And how do I overcome this dillema?

Answer (score 1):

The `libraries/cms/pagination/pagination.php` defines the JPagination class and I don't know exactly how overrides are merged in this class, anyway you could grab a pagination example from **protostar default template** that, as you see, doesn't use any reference to the main JPagination object and uses only the `$item` in parameters:

```
function pagination_item_active(&$item){
    $class = '';

    // Check for "Start" item
    if ($item->text == JText::_('JLIB_HTML_START')){
        $display = '<span class="icon-first"></span>';
    }

    // Check for "Prev" item
    if ($item->text == JText::_('JPREV')){
        $display = '<span class="icon-previous"></span>';
    }

    // Check for "Next" item
    if ($item->text == JText::_('JNEXT')){
        $display = '<span class="icon-next"></span>';
    }

    // Check for "End" item
    if ($item->text == JText::_('JLIB_HTML_END')){
        $display = '<span class="icon-last"></span>';
    }

    // If the display object isn't set already, just render the item with its text
    if (!isset($display)){
        $display = $item->text;
        $class   = ' class="hidden-phone"';
    }

    return '<li' . $class . '><a title="' . $item->text . '" href="' . $item->link . '" class="pagenav">' . $display . '</a></li>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm no PHP expert but I'll ***try*** to give a small technical reason as to what I believe the issue is in your case.

`$this->app->isAdmin()` is causing the error because the only object that is being passed through the function is `JPagination`, which is the `$item` variable, not `$this`.

Therefore to get the `JApplication` object, you'll need to manually define it like so:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
```

Then perform your check, like so:

```
if ($app->isAdmin())
{
    // Your code
}
```